# Creating a google sheet file in a shared drive using a gcp service account and google sheets api

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am creating a cloud function that creates a google sheet using the google sheets api. And then I am sharing the file with specific users.
I am not sure, in which user's google drive, the file is originally created. It may be the service account that runs the cloud function.
But, I want to create the file in a shared drive which other users have access to. Can I do that using the sheets api?

Or, how do I move this file to the shared drive?

Comment: Have you tried the solution I offered below?

Comment: Yes... But still I don't see the file in the specific drive. The operation was successful.  So, the service account that I'm using is a gcp service account and the shared drive is not in gcp. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Can you check the response and get the `webViewLink`? Open the link and check where the file has to ended up. Follow this [video](https://youtu.be/5_V5Ogf4_0k) after opening the link.

Comment: The file is properly created but ended up somewhere. You might have provided a wrong drive_id or shared_drive_id.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a spreadsheet directly into a folder by using the Drive API:

#### Sample:

```
const resource = {
    name: file_name,
    driveId: shared_drive_id,
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
    parents: [parent_id]
};

drive.files.create({
    resource,
    supportsAllDrives: true
});
```

#### Note:

- `parent_id` can be a sub folder within the shared drive or the root itself.
- You can also use the Sheets API to create the file, then Drive API to update the file with `addParents` to copy it to another folder, and `removeParents` to remove it from the root which was your initial creation folder. But I prefer to create it directly using the Drive API which is shown above.

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)